# can anyone please explain this left join output? I am new to this

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables with just one column.

```
p1 (id - 1,1,null)
p2(id - 1,1,null, null)
```

when I am doing left join

```
(select * from p1 left join p2 on p1.id = p2.id)
```

I am getting 5 rows

```
(1,1,1,1.null)
```

I was expecting to get 4 rows.
Please explain why.

Comment: I think that you unserstand why you get the 4 rows with 1s. The 5th row you get is the row with `null` in table `p1`. In a LEFT join **all** rows of the left table are returned.

Comment: Left join will return all the rows from your left table first, which is 3, then all the matching rows from the right table, for each row of '1', you will find 2 matching rows from the right table, so total 5 (2 rows for matching the 1st '1', 2 rows for matching the 2nd '1', the last 1 is nonmatching NULL)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33e6845/8 basically, you cannot join on NULL

Comment: You're getting a **cross join**  in this as well - each row with the value of 1 in p1 matches 2 rows in p2.  Would be easier to make sense of this with better sample data.

Comment: What *four* rows do you think you would get?  Look that the *two* columns from each side of the `join`.  What part don't you get?

Comment: Explain how you are stuclk applying the manual or your texbook to answering this. Don't ask us to rewrite them. [ask] [help] For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that 4 rows are for ID = 1 i.e. each ID = 1 in P1 will join with two rows in P2 with value 1 and like wise second 1 in P1 will again join with 2 rows in P2.

5th row is for Null.

Answer (score 1):

SQL left join is basically a join which will match the index on the left table with the right table plus all the non matched records of the left table.
Now left join is quite simple when you don't have duplicate rows

[image: SQL Table with no duplicate values]

As can be seen from the image, there are 5 records each in the left and right table and 3 of them match. So the SQL left join will return all the matched records once plus all the unmatched records and our final answer will be

> Ronaldo,Messi,Zidane,Terry and Pogba

Now what happens if there is a duplicate record in the right table like that in your case

[image: SQL table with duplicate records]

.

Now, since there are 2 records each for Messi and Zidane, the left join will return two records of Messi and Zidane and hence the final output will be

> Ronaldo,Messi,Messi,Zidane,Zidane,Terry and Pogba

Hope, I'm able to help in clarifying your doubt